# How to control the color wheel with shortcuts in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, shortcuts

Is there a way to increase and decrease saturation/value on the color wheel with shortcuts in photoshop?

[image: Color wheel]

For instance, when I press "W" the slider goes up towards the white

Comment: Not as far as I know.  Adobe publishes a list of the shortcuts on their website and there seems to be nothing like that listed. Also searching through Photoshop's various actions in the Keyboard Shortcuts dialog reveals nothing.

Comment: I didn't find it either, so I thought it was hidden somewhere hehe... By the way, do you know if it's possible to do this through programming like with plugins/extensions?